# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled [duplicated]

Tags: reactjs

I installed react-slot-machine-gen plugin, I call the component from App.js but it doesn't work, I get error:

```
 Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (38:7):
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets:[
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"]
}
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import Demo from "./components/Slot";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Demo />
    </div>
  );
}
```

react version is 16.14.0

Attached image of error
[jsx error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvKnJ.jpg)